# Retrieve data from Firebase by Refering to a Child's Index

Tags: java, database, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to access, one by one, the values inside of the 'Progress' Child, as can be seen in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7xNt.jpg). Having done my research, I cannot seem to find a function which allows me to refer to a child by its index. Is it possible to access these records by referring to some sort of index, such as [0], [1], [2] etc. as opposed to referring to their key?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database only allows accessing data by its path. There is no way to access data by a derived property such as its index/position.

If you need to access data by index, you should use the indices as the keys for those items. But note that Firebase in most cases recommends against doing this, as it hurts scalability and won't work while offline. See [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).